# SQL how to select the left table where it's id appears less than 5 times in the right table in the current week?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Below is my left table, `user`.

```
id    name 
1     a 
2     b
3     c
```

Below is my right table `user_present`

```
id    user_id    created_at 
1     1          2016-12-01 00:00:00
2     2          2016-12-01 01:00:00
3     2          2016-12-02 03:00:00 
4     1          2016-12-04 00:00:00
6     1          2016-12-05 00:00:00 
7     1          2016-12-06 00:00:00
8     1          2016-12-07 00:00:00 
9     1          2016-12-08 00:00:00 
10    2          2016-12-08 00:00:00 
11    2          2016-12-08 10:59:59
12    2          2016-12-09 10:59:59
```

How do I write the join query to get the following users as result, users who appears less than 5 times in the current week? Assume that the current date is `2016-12-09`

```
id    name 
2     b
3     c
```

User `a` will not be included because it appears 5 times in the right table between `2016-12-04` and `2016-12-10` which is the current week. We get only user `b` and `c` because `b` appears just 3 times in the current week and the previous 2 times were in the last week. That does not count. We get `c` as well because `c` does not yet appear in the right table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `having` clause and `count` with condition, try this:

```
select
   u.*
from `user` u
left join user_present up
on u.id = up.user_id
group by u.id, u.name
having count(
    case
        when week(up.created_at) = week('2016-12-09 00:00:00') then 1
        else null
    end
) < 5
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4e7f2/1) here.

Comment: Your query does not consider the current week. What I mean is that it only consider if a record in the left table appears 5 times or not, in total in the right table, even those records are in different weeks.

Comment: This is `week(up.created_at) = week('2016-12-09 00:00:00')`, which count user in the same week. Am I wrong? @OConnor

Comment: I replace the fixed date with week(NOW()), but I don't get B even there are only 3 B in the current week.

Comment: @OConnor Did you ever `select now()` and check if it'is right time or not?

Answer (score 0):

Using Forward's fiddle...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_user_present;

CREATE TABLE my_user
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO my_user
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b'),
    (3, 'c')
;


CREATE TABLE my_user_present
    (`id` int, `user_id` int, `created_at` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO my_user_present
    (`id`, `user_id`, `created_at`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2016-12-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2, '2016-12-01 01:00:00'),
    (3, 2, '2016-12-02 03:00:00'),
    (4, 1, '2016-12-04 00:00:00'),
    (6, 1, '2016-12-05 00:00:00'),
    (7, 1, '2016-12-06 00:00:00'),
    (8, 1, '2016-12-07 00:00:00'),
    (9, 1, '2016-12-08 00:00:00'),
    (10, 2, '2016-12-08 00:00:00'),
    (11, 2, '2016-12-08 10:59:59'),
    (12, 2, '2016-12-09 10:59:59')
;

SELECT u.* 
  FROM my_user u
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_user_present p
    ON p.user_id = u.id
   AND YEARWEEK(created_at) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) 
 GROUP 
    BY user_id 
HAVING COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) < 5;

id name
 3 c
 2 b
```

I was obliged to change the tablenames in rextester because there's an existing 'user' table there with some kind of foreign key constraint on it.

http://rextester.com/DXX71634

Comment: Are you sure you also get B with your query? Because I don't get it. It counts all B as 5 and did not consider the current week.

Comment: @OConnor Well, obviously. You're welcome to click on the link.

Comment: Why are you grouping by my_user_present.user_id instead of my_user.id?

Comment: I don't get it. I used your above query and I don't get B since it counts B as 5 in total. but on rextester.com you get B as well.

Comment: @OConnor As demonstrated, I cannot replicate your result.

Comment: You can GROUP BY either, as there is a functional dependency in play. Actually, I think it's better practice to GROUP BY u.id, but either way, it shouldn't affect the result.